# Android - Cannot initialize Google Places

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps

I have an app that uses a combination of Google Maps, Places and Firebase.

I am trying to use the Google places autocomplete widget for searching and then returning address locations for the map.  When trying to initialize Google Places I am getting an error `Cannot resolve symbol 'initialize'`

Here is my code:

MapsActivity

```
package com.k99studio.firemap;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.RectangularBounds;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.TypeFilter;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.Autocomplete;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.model.AutocompleteActivityMode;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private FirebaseAuth fbAuth;
    private FirebaseUser fbUser;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;

    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), YOUR_API_KEY);
    PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Loads the actionbar with custom menu maps_menu.xml
        getSupportActionBar();

        // Creates a listener than monitors the state of the firebase authentication.  If the state
        // of the authentication changes at any point during the app usage then the function will be
        // called.  If there is found to be no current user (logged out, token expired etc.) then
        // the user will be redirected to the sign in (Auth) activity.
        fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fbUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (fbUser == null){
                    startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, AuthActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Starts the authentication listener
        fbAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Stops the authentication listener.
        if (authStateListener != null) {
            fbAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Set default map location to Milton Fire Station
        LatLng miltonFireStation = new LatLng(-46.120031, 169.958416);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(miltonFireStation));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflates the custom menu options on to the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.maps_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handles button presses for buttons on the action bar and action bar menu
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.newMarker:
                // New marker.  Go to the new marker activity
                startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, CreateActivity.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.searchAddress:
                // Search button is pressed.  Start the google places auto complete search
                startAutocompleteActivity();
                return true;

            case R.id.mapStandard:
                //  Set google map type to Normal
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                return true;

            case R.id.mapSatellite:
                // Set google map type to Satellite
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                return true;

            case R.id.mapHybrid:
                // Set google map type to Hybrid
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                return true;

            case R.id.logOut:
                // Signs the users our of firebase authentication.  Should trigger the AuthStateListener
                // to return the user to the Auth Activity.
                fbAuth.signOut();
                return true;

            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

    private void startAutocompleteActivity() {
        // Auto complete search widget for google places.  To get address coordinates to return to the map location.
        List<com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place.Field> placeFields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place.Field.values()));
        List<TypeFilter> typeFilters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(TypeFilter.values()));
        // Create a RectangularBounds object.
        RectangularBounds bounds = RectangularBounds.newInstance(
                new LatLng(-33.880490, 151.184363),
                new LatLng(-33.858754, 151.229596));
        Intent autocompleteIntent =
                new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, placeFields)
                        .setLocationBias(bounds)
                        .setTypeFilter(typeFilters.get(0))
                        .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(autocompleteIntent, 1001);
    }
}
```

My dependencies are set up as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
```

I'm a bit baffled with this one since I've followed the instructions from the Google docs (I think).  I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Where is the `YOUR_API_KEY` ?

Comment: There isn't one.  Even when I did place one there it didn't work.  The function `initialize` isn't recognized as a valid function.  Intellisense ignores it completely.  I have tried to invalidate caches and restart.  It is happening on both my windows PC and Macbook.

Comment: `Places.initialize(context,
                "GOOGLE_ANDROID_API_KEY");` you need to call place init method first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did a very silly mistake here The `places.initialize()` function should be part of onCreate and not declared globally.
Your code will become..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), YOUR_API_KEY);
    PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    // Loads the actionbar with custom menu maps_menu.xml
    getSupportActionBar();

    // Creates a listener than monitors the state of the firebase authentication.  If the state
    // of the authentication changes at any point during the app usage then the function will be
    // called.  If there is found to be no current user (logged out, token expired etc.) then
    // the user will be redirected to the sign in (Auth) activity.
    fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fbUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (fbUser == null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, AuthActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Here's why.....

The library is initialized when the activity is created which is done in onCreate override method

Comment: I feel like such a knob.  Thanks heaps.  Supplementary question:  Where is the best place to store the actual api key in code so it's not uploaded to Github etc.

Comment: No worries, Thanks for accepting my answer. There is no place to store api key securely in android package, its best not to add api key anywhere when uploading to the github. Or you can encrypt the api key and add it in a txt file while uploading to github